# Minimum of centre of mass, hydrostatics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

A tube in the form of U is filled with water, in one end we pour some aditional oil. Find the height difference between the liquid surfaces on both ends. Hint: Find the minimum of the centre of mass $z_t=\frac{\int \rho(z)\space  z\space  dV}{\int \rho(z) dV}$ .

In my calculation $z_t = c +\frac{\int_{h_1} ^{h_2} \rho_1 S x dx+\int_{h_1} ^{h_3} \rho_2 S x dx}{M}$$=c+\frac{1}{2M}(\rho_1(h_2^2-h_1^2)+\rho_2 (h_3^2-h_1^2))$ (1)

Where c is just a constant from the integration over the circular part and doesnt play a role in the minimization of $z_t$, M is the whole mass, $\rho_{1,2}$ are densities, $h_1,h_3,h_2$ $\rightarrow$ see picture below...

Then I can express $h_1$ from the equilibrium equation $\rho_1(h_2-h_1)=\rho_2(h_3-h_1)$ and plug it into (1) and then I would need to find the derivative of that new equation with respect to $(h_3-h_1)$ and equate it to 0, to get the minimum: $\frac{\partial (...)}{\partial (h_3-h_1)}$=0   ? **But this gets me nowhere... Any suggestions? **

**Once again**: im trying to minimize $z_t$ with respect to $\delta h = h_3-h_1$ to find a equilibrium "position" of the system...  The right result (according to the book)  is: $\frac{\delta h}{h_3}=\frac{\rho_1}{\rho_2}-1$ .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have left some crucial information out of the problem : probably the amount of oil. Without that there is no way of finding the difference in heights, only the ratio of heights. The hint to find the minimum centre of mass is misleading.

$h_1$ can take any value without affecting the difference in height. So take $h_1=0$, ie start measuring $h_2$ and $h_3$ from the horizontal through the oil-water boundary. Then the equilibrium condition is $\rho_w g h_2=\rho_o g h_3$.

Assuming that you are given the values of $\rho_w, \rho_o$ - or at least their ratio -  then you can only find the ratio of heights. The difference will vary depending on how much oil you add to the tube. If the oil has $\frac34$ the density of water then 4cm of oil will balance against 3cm of water. If there is 4cm of oil in the tube the difference in heights will be 1cm; if there is 8cm of oil in the tube the height of the water is 6cm so the difference is 2cm. And so on.

Comment: How would one then find the result that's stated in the book? The ration between the height difference and $h_3$ ?